# Show "Loader" in Input Text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I would like to show a loader inside an `<input type="text" />` at the end.  I have an autocomplete field that can take some time to load its ajax query, and I would like to indicate to the user that a search is being performed by adding the loader.  Here's what I have:

```
            $(".autocomplete-ad-users").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var $element = $(this.element);

                    var $loader = $("<div data-initialize='loader' class='loader'></div>");

                    $element.after($loader);
                    //start loading spinner
                    $loader.loader();
                    $loader.loader('play');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Search/SearchADUsers',
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Name + " - " + item.UniqueId,
                                    value: item.Id,
                                    tag: item.UniqueId
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var success = $(event.target).data('success');

                    //this allows us to apply 'data-success="functionName"' to an input
                    //with this class to override the default select function.
                        if (success) {
                            window[success](event, ui);
                        }
                        else {
                            UserSelected(event, ui);
                        }
                    }
            });
```

Now I've watched my DOM tree during execution and the `$loader` element is being properly added after the input text, but it doesn't seem to have a height and it's not visible.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

**EDIT** Well I was missing my forward slash on the closing tag for the div, but that didn't solve the problem.

**EDIT** It may be important to know that the `input` field in question is on a bootstrap modal.

**EDIT** I've now gotten the `loader` element to display by adding `fuelux` class to the parent element.  But the `loader` is displaying beneath the input field.  How can I get it to display inside the input field at the end?  Changing `after()` to `append()` didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you give `<div class='loader'></div>` dimensions in CSS?

Comment: Well `loader` is defined by fuelux.  However, with your prompting I did discover that I needed to put `fuelux` in the parent for the style to be applied.  It is displaying now, but it is showing underneath the input text.  Any idea how I can get it inside the input field?

Comment: Yep, give it a `position:relative` and move it around with `top:-30px` for instance

Comment: Sweet!  Got it working.  It took me a second to figure out that loader is a font for scaling purposes (change `font-size` instead of `transform`, but it's looking great now.  If you want to write in an answer I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the loader inside the input (at least visually, not the HTML element itself), give it a `position:relative` and move it around with `top:-30px` for instance.